# ¿Cómo podría desactivar un botón dependiendo de si un email está ya registrado o no?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, formularios

tras haber hecho un check con AJAX para ver si un usuario existe o no en una base de datos para mostrar un mensaje e la pantalla, he pensado en desactivar el botón de "enviar" en el lapsus de tiempo en el que el usuario no ha cambiado su email (para evitar que envie formularios duplicados). El problema es que tras haberlo intentado a través de un check de cookies (cuando el usuario pone una dirección duplicada, se le asigna una cookie y a través de un setInterval recargo un condicional en el que si el usuario ya ha puesto un email no duplicado se le remueve la cookie) no funciona, no da errores ni de php ni en la consola.

Espero haberlo expresado todo bien, cualquier cosa me decís, dejo aquí los codes.

Code de PHP (Envío de AJAX):

```
<?php
$nirvana = "1";
require_once("DBController.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='".$_POST["email"]."'";
  $user_count = $db_handle->numRows($query);
  if($user_count>0) {
      echo "<span class='estado-no-disponible-email'> Este email ya está registrado.</span>";
    setcookie('used',$nirvana,time()+4737437, '/');



  }else{
        

    if (isset($_COOKIE['used'])) {
     setcookie('used',$nirvana,time()-4737437, '/');
}

        

  }
}


?>
```

Código de AJAX (check de email):

```
    function comprobarEmail() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "./assets/php/cosita.php",
    data:'email='+$("#email").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#estadoemail").html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });

   setInterval(function(){
    const bup = $.cookie('used');

    if (bup === "1") {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    $("#form_send").prop('disabled', true);

    
    });
}
else{
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      $("#form_sende").prop('disabled', false);
    
    });
}
}, 1000);


}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form_email">
            <label for="email">
                ¿Cuál es su e-mail? <span class="info_email">Solo lo usaremos para enviarte actualizaciones sobre tu postulación. </span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" title="Introduzca un email correcto." maxlength="30" onBlur="comprobarEmail(); emailsend(); " onpaste="return false"  required />
             <span id="estadoemail"></span> </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: No viene a cuento, ¿pero sabes que existe el `type="email"` para los elementos `input` que ya te verifica la sintaxis de un email? Mas info aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

Comment: @masterguru ah pues no lo sabía, gracias,